# Relating to future dated entries

Tags: relationships, related-entries

I've added a Relationships field to a Channel, which allows the current entry to be related to another Channel that contains events, however events that are going to take place in the future do not appear in the list of events that are available to link to.

So I can't relate to future dated entries.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that in the settings for your Relationship custom field that you have checked the box for "Include in selection *Future entries?*"

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew I'd seen that somewhere, but it was 'hidden' (ahm) amongst the Channels select and several other Select options